# SAS URI gets broken when trying to upload the vhd to blob container in a storage account

Tags: bash, azure-blob-storage, vhd

I am using a bash script ot upload a vhd to blob container in a storage account.

Steps:

- I created a VM, Storage account, container with blob acces, and snapshot. From the VM created, I'm generating one SAS URI by taking a snapshot of the VM Disk.
- After SAS URI is generated I'm trying to upload it to the storage account container using below CLI Command:

```
$sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)
```

I verified the value of `$sas` in the terminal it's printing the correct value.
But when try the below command.

```
az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $accountname --account-key $key --source-uri $sas

The SAS URI is a very large string. Wherever I see '&' in SAS URL the string after it gets separated.

Let's say the string is like `abc&sr63663&si74883&sig74848`

I'm getting the error:
```

sr is not recognized as internal or external command.
Si is not recognized as internal or external command.
Sig is not recognized as internal or external command.

```
Please help me with how I can pass the SAS URI properly in the last command mentioned through the bash script.
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:**

[image]

*To resolve the error, try wrapping the SAS token separately with ***single quotes followed by double quotes*** like below:*

```bash
$sastoken=' " your_sas_token" '

az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $accountname --account-key $key --source-uri $sastoken
```

***After executing the above script, vhd file uploaded to blob container successfully like below:***

[image]

***To confirm the above, Go to the Azure Portal and check the blob container like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to provide a SAS token to Azure CLI by Jon Tirjan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275292/how-to-provide-a-sas-token-to-azure-cli-within-powershell/47313365#47313365)